# Can't mount at boot my external usb disk formatted ntfs

Tags: boot, mount, ntfs, fstab, ntfs-3g

I have new external usb disk, I want to use it with ntfs because I need to use it with big files and with some devices that doesn't recognize linux ext partitions.
I get the "Transport endpoint is not connected" error so I googled, but can't find a solution.

The error:

```
fmf@kodi:~$ df -h
df: /media/library: Transport endpoint is not connected
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           386M  6.2M  380M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        88G   29G   55G  35% /
tmpfs           1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdd1       917G  812G   59G  94% /media/Tera
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
/dev/sdb1       917G  205G  667G  24% /media/Cloud
tmpfs           386M     0  386M   0% /run/user/1000
fmf@kodi:~$
```

Now my configuration:

```
fmf@kodi:~$sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 93.2 GiB, 100030242816 bytes, 195371568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a04b2

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 187211775 187209728 89.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       187213822 195371007   8157186  3.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       187213824 195371007   8157184  3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BACF5A78-71A6-4A24-8A4A-1D65DBC67DCA

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x01bea14b

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdd: 931.5 GiB, 1000202043392 bytes, 1953519616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2AE9D03B-6A9D-4259-A5AC-03EC79EB40EF

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 1953517567 1953515520 931.5G Linux filesystem
fmf@kodi:~$
```

The blkid output:

```
fmf@kodi:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="9fab4895-7ccb-4415-b26d-311a17036cda" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000a04b2-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="7b158f58-e4c1-4717-aa5f-dbeaa79ab93c" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="000a04b2-05"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="Tera" UUID="f9079f52-7661-48ad-9bc4-0d2452be66af" TYPE="ext2" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="7ba0b94d-b0c6-4e5d-9870-af445dd53358"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Cloud" UUID="fb1f92ee-54f5-44f8-ba92-544e90e6dfeb" TYPE="ext2" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="35d67138-5a9a-46ff-8133-829e93d310a4"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="library" UUID="72ACD728ACD6E61F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="01bea14b-01"
fmf@kodi:~$
```

And my fstab:

```
fmf@kodi:~$sudo cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9fab4895-7ccb-4415-b26d-311a17036cda /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=7b158f58-e4c1-4717-aa5f-dbeaa79ab93c none            swap    sw              0       0


#UUID=72ACD728ACD6E61F  /media/library  ntfs-3g  auto,users,uid=1000,gid=100,umask=0022,utf8  0  0
UUID=72ACD728ACD6E61F   /media/library  ntfs-3g auto,users,rw   0   0

UUID=f9079f52-7661-48ad-9bc4-0d2452be66af   /media/Tera ext2    defaults,nofail 0   0
UUID=fb1f92ee-54f5-44f8-ba92-544e90e6dfeb   /media/Cloud    ext2    defaults,nofail 0   0
fmf@kodi:~$
```

I can't access to the mount point:

```
fmf@kodi:~$ ll /media/
ls: cannot access '/media/library': Transport endpoint is not connected
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Sep  8 11:07 ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Sep  8 11:51 ../
drwxr-xr-x  4 fmf  fmf  4096 Jul  4 17:44 Cloud/
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? library/
drwxrwxr-x  6 fmf  fmf  4096 Jul  4 17:23 Tera/
fmf@kodi:~$
```

But if I unmount the disk via sudo and then remount it as user it works (notice the different permissions of the library directory):

```
fmf@kodi:~$ sudo umount /media/library
fmf@kodi:~$ ll /media/
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Sep  8 11:07 ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Sep  8 11:51 ../
drwxr-xr-x  4 fmf  fmf  4096 Jul  4 17:44 Cloud/
drwxr-xr-x  2 fmf  fmf  4096 Sep  6 21:30 library/
drwxrwxr-x  6 fmf  fmf  4096 Jul  4 17:23 Tera/
fmf@kodi:~$
fmf@kodi:~$ mount /media/library/
fmf@kodi:~$ ll /media/
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Sep  8 11:07 ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Sep  8 11:51 ../
drwxr-xr-x  4 fmf  fmf  4096 Jul  4 17:44 Cloud/
drwxrwxrwx  1 fmf  fmf  4096 Sep  8 11:46 library/
drwxrwxr-x  6 fmf  fmf  4096 Jul  4 17:23 Tera/
fmf@kodi:~$
```

And I can see the (empty) disk:

```
fmf@kodi:~$ ll /media/library/
total 160
drwxrwxrwx  1 fmf  fmf    4096 Sep  8 11:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root   4096 Sep  8 11:07 ../
fmf@kodi:~$
```

It seems to me that it's fstab that can't mount the disk because the user under it runs is not allowed to. But I don't even know if fstab runs with a user, so maybe I'm thinkng wrong.

Comment: Have you tried just formatting it with Gparted?

Comment: Check your BIOS-settings if fastboot is enabled.  disable fastboot and try if this helps. USB-features may not fully initialized if fastboot is enabled.

Comment: I have two other USB disks, one of them is the exact model of the one I'm havong problem with, and both of them are perfectly mounted at boot. The only difference is that those two are ext2 disks.

Comment: @AndroidDev: I don't really know why I shold format the disk with parted, it's already formatted in ntfs, what would do parted different?